# Flatten an array of arrays in javascript for get the longest string

Tags: javascript, arrays, list, reduce, flatten

I am trying to flatten an array of arrays in a input, and return the longest string.

For example given the input:

```
i = ['big',[0,1,2,3,4],'tiny']
```

The function should return *'tiny'*. I would like use [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) or [concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Concat) for resolve this in a native and elegant way (without implement a [flatten prototype in array](http://tech.karbassi.com/2009/12/17/pure-javascript-flatten-array/)) but I am failing with this code:

```
function longestStr(i) 
{
    // It will be an array like (['big',[0,1,2,3,4],'tiny'])
    // and the function should return the longest string in the array

    // This should flatten an array of arrays
    var r = i.reduce(function(a, b)
    {
         return a.concat(b);
    });

    // This should fetch the longest in the flattened array
    return r.reduce(function (a, b) 
        { 
            return a.length > b.length ? a : b; 
        });
}
```

Comment: I don't think you can JavaScript under pressure ...

Comment: Why don't you just work recursively instead of flattening the array?

Comment: @Poinly yep, I fail in level 4 :)

Comment: @n.st I try recursive for solve the problem and It works, but previously I cannot get with this reduce/contact solution, so I think that someone can help me

Comment: I just noticed that the task does not in fact require you to recurse into any sub-arrays.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your issue is that you forgot to pass in the `initialValue` argument to the [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) function, which must be an array in this case.

```
var r = i.reduce(function(a, b) {
    return a.concat(b);
}, []);
```

Without providing an `initialValue`, the `a` value for the first call will be the first element in the `i` array, which is the string *big* in your case, so you will be calling the `String.prototype.concat` function instead of `Array.prototype.concat`.

That means at the end, `r` is a string and strings don't have a `reduce` function.

Your solution could be simplified however:

```
['big',[0,1,2,3],'tiny'].reduce(function longest(a, b) {
    b = Array.isArray(b)? b.reduce(longest, '') : b;
    return b.length > a.length? b : a;
}, '');
```

Comment: Oh! Just that! I think that you win the accepted answer for now, but other answers proposed are very good too.

Comment: @shakaran I updated the answer with another solution.

Comment: @shakaran I've deleted my answer, the code provided by plalx is way better. And he also answered your question.

Comment: @JonKoops You still had a nice solution. Using `Array.prototype.concat.apply` to flatten was quite elegant.

Comment: @plalx Yeah, but unfortunately it does not flatten an array with more than 2 dimensions (not in the question but still important). I like the way you give the function a name and pass it in as an argument, I'm gonna remember that one.

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention having multiple strings with the same length-
or if you care about IE8...

```
function longestStr(A){
    var i= 0, len, A= String(A).split(/\b/).sort(function(a, b){
        return a.length<b.length;
    });
    len= A[0].length;
    while(A[i].length==len)++i;
    return A.slice(0, i);
}

var A1= ['big', [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], 'tiny',[1,2,3,'puny']];
longestStr(A1);

/*  returned value: (Array)
tiny,puny
*/
```

Method 2:

You did not define a string as a single word-

any array delimeters could be included in any of the values, making my solution incorrect.

Flattening the array makes comparing each item's length simple-

and it does not have to be done as a prototype method:

```
function longestStr(array){
    function flatten(arr){
        var A1= [], L= arr.length, next;
        for(var i= 0; i<L; i++){
            next= arr[i];
            if(next.constructor!= Array) A1.push(String(next));
            else A1= A1.concat(flatten(next));
        }
        return A1;
    }
    var i= 0, len, A=flatten(array);
    A.sort(function(a, b){
        return a.length<b.length;
    });
    len= A[0].length;
    while(A[i].length== len)++i;
    return A.slice(0, i);
}
var Ax= ['big stuff', [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], 'tiny', [1, 2, 3, 'puny']];
longestStr(Ax);

/*  returned value: (Array)
big stuff
*/
```

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that IE8 and lower doesn't have [reduce support](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ff679975(v=vs.94).aspx). Your solution is very good too for missing support of concat and reduce. Maybe this gets better perfomance than native solution with reduce or concat?

Comment: @shakaran Never hesitate to use native features because of legacy browsers that dont support them. Just use a shim such as https://github.com/kriskowal/es5-shim

Comment: @plalx nice, very useful library!